# Disable button till the combobox loads

Tags: c#, combobox

I am trying to disable a button till a combobox on the same screen loads. For this I have writeen the following code :

When screen loads :

```
TabButton okButton = _tabMultipleButtons.ListButtons.Find(a => a.ButtonType == TabButtonType.Confirm);
Action act = () => { okButton.Enabled = false; };

if (okButton.InvokeRequired)
    okButton.BeginInvoke(act);
else
    okButton.Invoke(act);
```

Combobox on change of index :

```
private void CmbBoxOrgUnitSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    TabButton okButton = _tabMultipleButtons.ListButtons.Find(a => a.ButtonType == TabButtonType.Confirm);
    Action action = () => { okButton.Enabled = true; };

    if (okButton.InvokeRequired)
        okButton.BeginInvoke(action);
    else
        okButton.Invoke(action);  
}
```

When I run the application, before the combobox loads, if I click the button, it is disabled. But as soon as combobox loads, the click event fires up. It seems like the click of button in disabled state is carried forward in the enabled state.

I am not sure why this is happening. It might be possible that change in the property might not occur in between events.

I also tried to set the text of button to empty string when the screen loads and again set the text to **Ok** when combobox loads, to check the visual change during this event. But the text was never set to empty string. It always appeared to be **Ok**.

Comment: Why not set `okButton` to be disabled at the first place then?

Comment: @TzahMama : Doing this was my first approach. But it does not work.

Comment: _But it does not work_ means it has the same behavior or the button isn't disabled? also are you using winforms or wpf?

Comment: @TzahMama : I am using compact framework. They are subset of winforms.